# Автоматическая выгрузка DLL из адресного пространства процесса.

Tags: winapi, windows, dll

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть приложение, использующее некий функционал из DLL. Подгрузка осуществляется динамически, т.е связкой `LoadLibrary -> GetProcAdress`. Приложение функционирует вполне себе нормально до перехода компьютера в спящий режим и последующего выхода из него. DLL-библиотека автоматически выгружается из адресного пространства, как ни странно, не сразу после выхода из спящего режима, а минут, этак, через 30-40. Как известно, спящий режим замораживает все процессы и, соответственно, потоки процессов до возообновления работы( выхода из сна ). Так вот, почему же после этих самых 30-40 минут, система определяет DLL, подгруженную в адресное пространство процесса приложения невалидной, бесполезной и автоматически выгружает из памяти? Как это можно исправить?

Спасибо.

Comment: @karmadro4, если вы не понимаете о чем идет речь в вопросе, это не повод его минусовать =)

Comment: Действительно не понимаю ни я, ни (как окажется в [итоге](http://hashcode.ru/questions/77926)) один из желающих разобраться в бредовой малой посылке, и вы будете кричать о том как хорошо разбираетесь в теме :-) Было уже.

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема никак не связана со спящим режимом. Предполагаю, что причина в лишнем вызове FreeLibrary.

Comment: @ganouver, FreeLibrary в коде программы отсутствует вовсе, т.к при завершении процесса все и так выгрузится из памяти автоматически. Данный баг напрямую связан с переходом в спящий режим...в других случаях такого не происходит. Спасибо.

Comment: Система не настолько умна.. Будучи загруженной библиотека остается загруженной пока счетчик ссылок не обнулится. Кроме FreeLibrary может быть вызывается какой-нить CloseHandle. 
P.S. Чудес не бывает. Нужно внимательно и критично изучить все, что происходит с хендлом, возвращаемым из LoadLibrary

Comment: Вот, об этом я писал( ну по крайней мере пытался ). Так, думаете, это невозможно?

Comment: В самом деле, минусовать непонятные вопроы (даже если автор заблуждается) **нехорошо**.

@Asen, то что Вы описали это интересно (плюсую). 

Реально многие пользователи отмечают *странности* в поведении разных программ в Windows при выходе из сна (на notebook). С чем это связано - не знаю. Могу предположить, что наблюдаемое @Asen "пропадание" dll из той же оперы.

*Места в комментарии как всегда* ***мало***

Comment: @avp, да, очень это странно и непонятно, почему система выгружает рабочую DLL из памяти...

Comment: -*продолжение*-

Это только предположение, основано на умозрительных построениях.

--

Допустим, система при работе изредка  "теряет" некоторые страницы. 

Т.е. они остаются в таблицах адресного пространства процесса, но исчезают из списка размещенных физических страниц и не попадают в список занятых. (Список условное название, реализация м.б. совсем другой). 

Тогда, при засыпании системы, их содержимое не будет выгружено на диск. Соответственно не будет восстановлено при пробуждении, и что реально будет в ОЗУ непредсказуемо.

--

Еще раз по поводу вопроса - *требуется тщательное изучение*.

Comment: Проблема в том, что автор не заблуждается, а уже заблудился и теперь придется доказывать, что якобы прочитанное в MSDN и показавшееся "*под дизассемблером*" не соответствует действительности.

> многие пользователи отмечают странности в поведении разных программ в Windows при выходе из сна

Я, наверное, что-то делаю неправильно, т.к. никаких чудес не воспроизводится.

Comment: @avp Слабо верится, что при реализации `Hibernate` в `Microsoft` допустили возможность непредсказуемого состояния ОЗУ в момент восстановления из этого самого `Hibernate`. Недетерминированное состояние в этом случае в 204904590 раз критичнее, скажем, обычной утечки памяти.

Comment: @karmadro4, рад за Вас. Конфигуратор от HP проделывает эти фокусы регулярно.

@Котик, охотно верю, что объяснение неработоспособности после Hibernate м.б. другим. 

Кстати, "фокусы" в Windows возникают и просто при интенсивной работе, явно вызывающей "тяжелый" свопинг.

Comment: @avp, это мало о чем говорит, кроме того, что у НР *где-то* баг. Но если его так описать, то не примут с причиной "Не воспроизводится".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На 98% уверен, что обнуляется счетчик ссылок,
полностью поддерживаю [[@ganouver](/users/2087/ganouver)](/users/2087/ganouver),
это же подтверждает валидная работа библиотеки при статической линковке.

При обнулении счетчика, память, в которую отображается библиотека не всегда может быть высвобождена, поэтому возникает иллюзия, что все работает правильно (адреса могут быть корректны).

В спящем режиме, по всей видимости происходит оптимизация виртуального пространства процессов, после которой все иллюзии рассеиваются.

Answer (score -1):

- Советую вам попробовать заменить подход с `GetProcAdress` + `LoadLibrary` на подход с генерацией `static import library` для `dll'ки` и ее линковкой к своему приложению.

> Если в этом случае проблема пропадет, то можно будет говорить о непонятном поведении ОС касательно загруженных `dll'ок`. Допускайте также вариант некорректного использования `LoadLibrary` в принципе *(сверьтесь с `MSDN`).*

Comment: Статический импорт пробовал. Все работает правильно, как ни странно! Но в этом случае будет не совсем удобно. Придется много кода переписывать, т.к приложение не малое, и экспортируемый DLL функционал подключается динамически. Спасибо.

Comment: Боюсь, что в таком случае без фрагмента кода сложно что-либо сказать. Можете проверить поведение на разных системах, если оно `persist'ится`, то, думаю, что ошибка точно в коде.

Comment: А в чем же может заключаться ошибка, раз выгрузка системой происходит только после спящего режима и НИКОГДА больше?

Comment: @Asen А как вы можете доказать, что она не происходит НИКОГДА больше? :)

Comment: На протяжении всего времени, что разрабатываю приложение( около 3 месяцев ), регулярно тестировал его, выгрузки не возникало. Это точно, в эту сторону можно не смотреть.

Comment: @Asen, предположение конечно бредовое, но может после Hibernate DllMain() вызывается и Вы что-то неправильно обрабатываете ?